# wxDataViewCtrl and DnD

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am using wxWidgets 3.0.2 with Gtk on Linux.

I am trying to make a wxDataViewCtrl a drop target for a drag and drop operation.  I derived a class from wxTextDropTarget and then made a call to wxDataViewCtrl::SetDropTarget() to make an instance of this class to be the drop target for the wxDataViewCtrl.

However, nothing happens.  Every time I try to drop something on the wxDataViewCtrl, the wxDropSource::DoDragDrop() method returns wxDragCancel.  For my custom wxTextDropTarget class, I overrode the OnEnter() method and had it write to stdout "OnEnter()" whenever I entered the wxDataViewCtrl with something to drop, but nothing gets written to stdout.

To test that I am even doing the custom wxTextDropTarget class right and setting up the drop source correctly, I added a wxTextCtrl to my GUI and made that the drop target and everything worked as expected:  wxDropSource::DoDragDrop() returned wxDragCopy and "OnEnter()" would get written to stdout when I entered the wxTextCtrl with something to drop.

Does wxDataViewCtrl not support DnD?  Or is there something else I am overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just thought I'd follow up on my own post in case somebody else runs into the same problem.

After writing a small test program just to test DnD between a control and a wxDataViewCtrl and discovering that it works fine, I went back to my original application and stared at it for a bit longer to try and figure out what was I was doing differently.  It turns out that I needed to call SetDropTarget() on the PARENT window of the target wxDataViewCtrl and not the wxDataViewCtrl itself, i.e. my_data_view_ctrl->GetParent()->SetDropTarget(blah blah blah);.

However, I didn't have to do this in my test program, so I thought it was a bit weird.  The only difference between my test program and my actual program was that in my actual program, I have the wxDataViewCtrl inside a wxStaticBoxSizer and I think that was problem.  I suspect that the wxStaticBox (that the wxStaticBoxSizer uses) was getting the drop notification instead of the wxDataViewCtrl, hence why I needed to set it's SetDropTarget() rather than the wxDataViewCtrl.